# TypeError: this._config.server.rewriteRequestUrl is not a function

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg, metro-bundler

I've been using `yarn start` and `expo start` to see my apps made in React Native.

The app opens if I open it in web browser itself, but it shows the following error in console during Android Studio emulator

```
Opening exp://192.168.1.2:19000 on Pixel_3a_API_30
TypeError: this._config.server.rewriteRequestUrl is not a function
    at Server._processRequest (C:\STUDY\Github-User-n-Repo-Searcher\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:364:35)    
    at processRequest (C:\STUDY\Github-User-n-Repo-Searcher\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:351:10)
    at call (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)      
    at next (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)      
    at next (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:161:14)     
    at next (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:161:14)     
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
    at call (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)      
    at next (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)      
    at remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware (C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\middleware\remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware.ts:31:3)
```

I think the problem is because I used yarn and npm to install different dependencies. How can I revert back now? Or is there any other solution?

Edit: The error is just in this particular app, other developed apps are working fine in emulator as well.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: No, I had to restrict the project to a web app only.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Thats interesting

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded the metro package to the latest version and the error is gone:

```
"metro-config": "^0.66.2",
```

Comment: I'll try it soon and give update here